# Compare length of 2 variables and assign longest to another variable

Tags: php, php-7

I have 2 arrays of differing length assigned to $array1 and $array2,

Is there a more graceful way of checking each of there lengths and then assigning the biggest to a new variable?

Below is what i already have, but it seems a bit to 'dirty'.

```
if ($array1 > $array2) {
    $PlayerSum = $array1;
}
elseif ($array2 > $array1) {
    $PlayerSum = $array2;
}
else {
    $error = "<div class='alert alert-danger error'>Invalid Entry!</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use a simple [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
if (count($array1) > count($array2)) {
    $PlayerSum = $array1;
}
elseif (count($array2) > count($array1)) {
    $PlayerSum = $array2;
}
else {
    // the 2 arrays must be the same length
    $error = "<div class='alert alert-danger error'>Invalid Entry!</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **sizeof()**

```
 if (sizeof($array1) > sizeof($array2) {
    $PlayerSum = $array1;
}
elseif (sizeof($array2) > sizeof($array1) {
    $PlayerSum = $array2;
    }
    else {
        $error = "<div class='alert alert-danger error'>Invalid Entry!</div>";
    }
```